# Hardcode Hibernate values in Java code

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create JUnit test with hardcoded Hibernate configuration values:

```
public class UserProvisionTest
{
        public static SessionFactory buildTestSessionFactory()
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:sqlite:/Users/Desktop/testDB.sqlite");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.sqlite.JDBC");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "auto");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.autoReconnect", "true");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(SystemUserModel.class);

        configuration.configure();
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
        System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.apache.naming");

        return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Test
    public void createUsersTest() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Creating default users");

        Session session = buildTestSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

        // some query
        session.flush();
        tr.commit();
    }
}
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)      
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/sqliteDB]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name java:comp is not bound in this Context
```

Can you give me some advice how I can solve this issue?
Looks like this custom configuration is not valid.

EDIT: Pom file content with my configuration:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.web.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>Web_package</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Web_package</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SQLite JDBC library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--JBoss/Weld Refrence Implementation for CDI on a Servlet Container -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.53</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.gwenn</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>d285e22851</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Web_package</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        .......
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I'm pasting here the content for the POM.xml file.

Comment: What's hibernate version you use?

Comment: @ArtemNovikov I use the latest version.

Comment: Did anything help?

Comment: No, I still have the same issue.

Comment: Show the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove this line, because it tries to read from `hibernate.cfg.xml` which you don't have and don't need (that's why it tries to make a JNDI lookup, while you didn't tell it to do so).

`configuration.configure()`

2. Consequently, for proper programmatic configuration, change this line

`return configuration.buildSessionFactory();`

to this

```
configuration.buildSessionFactory(
    new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
        .build()
);
```

Comment: Very good answer but looks like ServiceRegistryBuilder() is deprecated. I can't find the package hibernate-core - 5.2.12.Final

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it for your latest hibernate. It should be `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`.

Comment: I get Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/sqliteDB]   and Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Comment: Please, in your question, add the contents of your pom.xml file. Or gradle, if you use gradle.

Comment: Well on my side with my changes and your pom everything works. Please, check that you applied my changes correctly. Also, let's try this connection url: `jdbc:sqlite:testDB.sqlite`

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by

> Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/sqliteDB]

it can't find the name `com/env/jdbc/sliteDB`

You might wish to download the jdbc driver and install the jar into your project.

https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/

Or if you use maven, list it as a dependency.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```